# Evaluating derivatives of functions of three variables in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to evaluate the derivative of a function at a point (3,5,1) in Mathematica. So, thats my input:

```
   In[120]:= D[Sqrt[(z + x)/(y - 1)] - z^2, x]
   Out[121]= 1/(2 (-1 + y) Sqrt[(x + z)/(-1 + y)])
   In[122]:= f[x_, y_, z_] := %
   In[123]:= x = 3
             y = 5
             z = 1
             f[x, y, z]
   Out[124]= (1/8)[3, 5, 1]
```

As you can see I am getting some weird output. Any hints on evaluating that derivative at (3,5,1) please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result you get for `Out[124]` leads me to believe that `f` was not cleared of a previous definition. In particular, it appears to have what is known as an [`OwnValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/OwnValues.html) which is set by an expression of the form

```
f = 1/8
```

(Note the lack of a colon.) You can verify this by executing

```
g = 5;
OwnValues[g]
```

which returns

```
 {HoldPattern[g] :> 5}
```

Unfortunately, `OwnValues` [supersede](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127/52) any other definition, like a function definition (known as a [`DownValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/DownValues.html) or, its variant, an [`UpValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UpValues.html)). So, defining

```
g[x_] := x^2
```

would cause `g[5]` to evaluate to `5[5]`; clearly not what you want. So, [`Clear`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Clear.html) any symbols you intend to use as functions prior to their definition. That said, your definition of `f` will still run into problems.

At issue, is your use of [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetDelayed.html) (`:=`) when defining `f`. This prevents the right hand side of the assignment from taking on a value until `f` is executed later. For example,

```
D[x^2 + x y, x]
f[x_, y_] := %

x = 5
y = 6
f[x, y]
```

returns `6`, instead. This occurs because `6` was last result generated, and `f` is effectively a synonym of [`%`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Out.html). There are two ways around this, either use `Set` (`=`)

```
Clear[f, x, y]
D[x^2 + x y, x];
f[x_, y_] = %

f[5, 6]
```

which returns `16`, as expected, or ensure that `%` is replaced by its value before `SetDelayed` gets its hands on it,

```
Clear[f, x, y]
D[x^2 + x y, x];
f[x_, y_] := Evaluate[%]
```

Comment: @Dostre Most of the experts on Mathematica have moved over to their own stackexchange site: [Mathematica.se]. If you have any more questions on Mathematica, it would be worthwhile posting there, instead.